# Cakephp ClassRegistry::init

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this code:

```
$userObj = ClassRegistry::init('User');
$userObj->contain();
$conditions = "User.studio_id = '".$studioID."' AND User.usergroup_id = 5";
$studioAdmin = $userObj->find($conditions);
```

The one that is causing the error is this line:

```
$studioAdmin = $userObj->find($conditions);
```

When I say error, it does not print anything or any warning of error, it just stops the code below it, I noticed that one because when I try to `echo` a code above it, it prints it, but when I try to `echo` a code below it, it does not print anything,

What is the problem here. Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The better practice way of loading models in components is to go via the controller, and use loadModel()

In your component, set up the initialize()

```
function initialize($controller, $settings) {
    $this->Controller =& $controller;
}
```

Then in your component function, use loadModel to load the model

```
$this->Controller->loadModel('Modelname');
$this->Modelname->save($data);
```

and also for find condition

```
$users = $this->Modelname->find('all', array(
   'conditions' => array(
       'User.studio_id'    => $studioID,
       'User.usergroup_id' => 5
   )
));
```

Comment: if you load the model via controller its not available in the component, but in the controller again!

Comment: @liyacat: You are incorrect. If you are doing `$this->Controller->loadModel('Modelname');` then in order to access that Model, you will do `$this->Controller->Modelname->find('...');` Your method would result in an error because you are trying to call a property/method of a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this:

```
$studioAdmin = $userObj->find('all', array( 'conditions' => $conditions ) );
```

Do you have PHP error messaging turned on? Did you check your logs to see what the specific error is?

Also, by cake standards, it is better to build your conditions clause this way:

```
$conditions = array(
                "User.studio_id" => $studioID,
                "User.usergroup_id" => 5"
              );
```

Comment: When I tried that one, it gave me an error like this:
Error: Call to a member function getController() on a non-object

Comment: what on earth are you trying to do? Where are you trying to initialize this model?

Comment: I would need to see your entire controller or model or wherever you are trying to initiate this model in order to get a better idea of what you are doing.